# How to Use Data Disk from Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a service fabric .net application that needs more temporary storage than is available on the instance.  The current instance allows for up to 4 data disks.  I see how to allocate these from the scale set, but not how to specify mounts, permissions, or even how to properly access them from the file API.  I was surprised to find very little in the way of documentation on this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get into the instance of the scale then you add new disk to the VM using instruction here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps

After that you can access them using standard IO i.e System.IO.File.ReadAllText

However it is not recommend to change node type for primary node and for non primary node type it is better to create a new vm scale set. Graduate move services from old scale set to the new one by update placement properties